# Extract number after a point in ID number column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dataset

So here is one of the column I have in my dataset in R :

| ID |
| --- |
| 1.34789 |
| 1.90763 |
| 63107 |
| 84749 |
| 1.02195 |

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

| ID |
| --- |
| 34789 |
| 90763 |
| 63107 |
| 84749 |
| 02195 |

I only found codes about strings and sentences but none for this kind of situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With stringr you can do:

```r
id <- c(1.34789, 1.90763, 63107, 84749, 1.02195)

library(stringr)


str_remove(id, "^\\d+\\.")
#> [1] "34789" "90763" "63107" "84749" "02195"

#Or using base r `gsub`

gsub("^\\d+\\.", "", id)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot !! I tried with sub(".*.","",df$id) in a first place but it didn't extract anything.

Comment: Oh yes sorry, i'm new here so i was not aware of that ! It's done

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `gsub` with regex `\\b1.\\b`

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c(1.34789,1.90763,63107,84749,1.02195))

gsub(pattern = "\\b1.\\b",replacement = "",x = df$ID,perl = T)


[1] "34789" "90763" "63107" "84749" "02195"
```